# Help parsing a question about scalar line integrals?

Tags: calculus, integration, definite-integrals, vector-analysis

I am told:

$C$ is the part of the circle $\frac{x^2}{6^2}+\frac{y^2}{6^2}=1$ in the first quadrant, find the following line integral with respect to arc length:

$\int_C(8x-5y)ds$

So I understood that we are simply computing:

$\int_C f(r(t))|c'(t)|dt$

we can express the curve $C$ as $y=\sqrt{36-x^2}$ or equivalently as $r(t)=\langle t,\sqrt{36-t^2} \rangle$

The range in this case would be $0\leq t \leq 6$ and thus I get:

$r'(t)=\langle1,\frac{-t}{\sqrt{36-t^2}}\rangle$

$|r'(t)|=\sqrt{1+\frac{t^2}{36-t^2}}=\sqrt{\frac{36}{36-t^2}}$

And thus the integral is:

$\int_6^0 (8t-5\sqrt{36-t^2})\frac{6}{\sqrt{36-t^2}})dt$

$=\int_6^0\frac{48t}{\sqrt{36-t^2}}-30$

The indefinite integral being:

$F(t)=-48\sqrt{36-t^2}-30t+C$

Thus the final answer should be: $-108$

(I skipped a couple of steps for shortness)

This answer is apparently wrong and I am not sure why exactly. I would appreciate help mostly with the reading comprehension of the question. What exactly does it mean by "with respect to arc length" is that equivalent with "along the curve $C$"? and if not why not?

Comment: What is the book's answer? Does it only differ by a sign, or a different number entirely? Notice that your answer parametrizes along the clockwise direction. The solution may have used a different parametrization.

Comment: It's a website not aboook, so all the information I have is "it's wrong".

Comment: That's unfortunate.

Comment: quite unfortunate

Comment: Try entering $108$ instead?

Comment: Worked, but why exactly must the bounds of integration be 0 to 6 and not 6 to 0? 6 to 0 along x follows the same direction as positive radians no?

Comment: The direction of integration is arbitrary, so the final answer is defined up to a negative sign. You're correct that the limits you put follow positive radians, but this isn't mentioned anywhere in the question. When in doubt, ignore the sign.